# issue in sending the socket output to GUI

Tags: java, swing, sockets

I wrote this simple multi threaded chatroom, and I am trying to send the client/server output to GUI to display it in chatroom text area but I get null pointer exception at the following line:

```
output.write(line + "\n");
```

here is the full code for GUI:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.JButton; 
import java.io.Writer;


public class GUI {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton btnSend, btnConnect;
    private JTextArea txtChat;
    private JTextField fldText, fldName;
    private JList clientList;
    private DefaultListModel listModel;
    private JScrollPane sc, scClients;
    private JPanel jpS2All, jpS2Client, jpS2Text;
    private String Name;
    private JLabel lblErr;
    private Writer output;

    public GUI(String Name, Writer output) {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.output = output;
    }

    public GUI() {

    }


    class handler implements ActionListener, MouseListener {

        handler(String Name) {

        }

        handler() {

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {


            clients();                 //it seems this line made the error because it creates the 
            listModel.addElement(Name);//gui and sends the output to textSend actionlistener
                                       //to display it in gui
                                       //while the output is empty, right?  
                                       //is there any way to handle this?

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            fldName.setText("");
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        }

    } //end of handler

    class textSend implements ActionListener {

        textSend(String Name, Writer output) {

        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            String line = fldText.getText();
            try {
                output.write(line + "\n");             // the null exception error shows the
                output.flush();                        // error source at this line!
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                txtChat.append("Other party hung up!");
            }
            String contenet = Name + ":" + output;
            txtChat.append(contenet);
            fldText.setText("");
        }

    }//end of textSend

    public void creatServer() {

        frame = new JFrame("enter");
        frame.setBounds(50, 50, 300, 200);
        btnConnect = new JButton("connect");
        lblErr = new JLabel();
        lblErr.setText("");
        frame.add(btnConnect, BorderLayout.EAST);
        fldName = new JTextField();
        fldName.setText("enter your name");
        fldName.addMouseListener(new handler());

        btnConnect.addActionListener(new handler(getName()));

        frame.add(fldName, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }


    public void clients() {    //to create the chatroom GUI
        frame = new JFrame("friends");
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 400, 400);
        jpS2All = new JPanel();
        txtChat = new JTextArea();
        txtChat.setRows(25);
        txtChat.setColumns(25);
        txtChat.setEditable(false);

        sc = new JScrollPane(txtChat);
        jpS2All.add(sc);
        frame.add(jpS2All, BorderLayout.WEST);
        jpS2Text = new JPanel();

        ////////////////////////
        fldText = new JTextField();
        fldText.setColumns(34);
        fldText.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.RIGHT);
        fldText.addActionListener(new textSend(getName(), output));
        jpS2Text.add(fldText);
        frame.add(jpS2Text, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        /////////
        jpS2Client = new JPanel();

        listModel = new DefaultListModel();
        clientList = new JList(listModel);
        clientList.setFixedCellHeight(14);
        clientList.setFixedCellWidth(100);
        scClients = new JScrollPane(clientList);

        frame.add(jpS2Client.add(scClients), BorderLayout.EAST);
        /////////
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }//end of clients

    public String getName() {
        Name = fldName.getText();
        return Name;
    }

    public void appendText(final String message) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                txtChat.append(message);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

server code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class server {

    public void start() throws IOException {
        ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            ClientThread t = new ClientThread(socket);
            t.start();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        server server = new server();
        server.start();

    }

    class ClientThread extends Thread {

        Socket socket;
        InputStream sInput;
        OutputStream sOutput;
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        String Name;

        ClientThread(Socket socket) {
            this.socket = socket;

        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                BufferedReader sInput
                        = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                Writer sOutput = new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
                Name = gui.getName();
                gui = new GUI(Name, sOutput);

                try {
                    String line;
                    while ((line = sInput.readLine()) != null) {
                        gui.appendText(line);
                    }
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

client side:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class client {

    private Socket s;
    private String Name;
    private GUI gui;
    private Writer output;
    private BufferedReader input;

    public void start() {

        try {
            s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 1234);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
        try {
            input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
            output = new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream());
        } catch (IOException eIO) {

        }
        Name = gui.getName();
        new GUI(Name, output);
        new ListenFromServer().start();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        client cl = new client();
        GUI gui = new GUI();
        gui.creatServer();
    }

    class ListenFromServer extends Thread {

        public void run() {
            try {
                String line;
                while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                    gui.appendText(line);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }

    }

}
```

I know my question is a bit cumbersome but I really appreciate to help me handle this issue!

Comment: In your default constructor `GUI gui = new GUI();` you don't ever initialize `output` and therefore it is always `null`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: also consider using `Anonymous` classes to define your action listeners...it cuts down on a lot of code

Comment: you mean the gui at the client thread class in the server side?
and the gui at the main method in the client side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error message shows that one of the variable used in the expression was null. This may be either `output` or `line`.

As chancea already mentioned, you are calling the GUI() constructor with no arguments, so the `output` field is not initialized. You should remove the constructor with no arguments when you have no way to initialize the `output` field in it and only leave the one with arguments.

Answer (score 2):

I am looking at your code and it is obvious that `output` is `null` when you attempt `output.write(line + "\n");` Therefore I went and looked for the possible path of execution that could leave `output` un-initialized.  This is where debugging comes in very handy.

Here is your execution path:

In your main method of `client` you create a new `GUI` and then call `gui.creatServer();`

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    client cl = new client();
    GUI gui = new GUI();
    gui.creatServer();
}
```

**output has not been assigned and is still null**

in the `creatServer();` method you have this line:

```
    fldName.addMouseListener(new handler());
```

which the `actionPerformed` method of `handler` calls the `clients();` method which has the line:

```
fldText.addActionListener(new textSend(getName(), output));
```

note `output` is **still null**

(now your `textSend` class doesn't even do anything inside the constructor but that aside even if it did you are still using the `output` variable from the `GUI` class)

you have the `actionPerformed` method in the `textSend` class that has the line:

```
output.write(line + "\n");
```

Without ever initializing `output` it is still null, which gives you the `NullPointer`

Please see [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) as @markspace linked in the comments.  In addition you should really learn how to debug small programs.

See the following links:

http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smallbasic/archive/2012/10/09/how-to-debug-small-basic-programs.aspx

Again in addition, consider using [Anonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) classes to ease up on those lines of code, which also makes the code easier to debug and more readable.

One last thought, remember to use standard [Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) for the language you are using.  your code currently has a lot of incorrect lowercase classes and some uppercase methods/properties.